# Set SelectedItem after updating SourceList/ReadOnlyObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, reactiveui

Using ReactiveUI/DynamicData, I'm having trouble figuring out how to set the `SelectedItem` of a ComboBox after I update `ItemSource`.  I'm using a `SourceList<T>` to hold the mutable collection along with a Connect/Bind/Subscribe to update a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` that is bound to the `ComboBox.ItemSource`.

The `ComboBox` is bound like so in the View:

```
            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.EventYearsList, v => v.EventYearsComboBox.ItemsSource).DisposeWith(d);
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.SelectedEventYear, v => v.EventYearsComboBox.SelectedItem).DisposeWith(d);
```

In the ViewModel I define a `ReactiveCommand` to update the `SourceList`, a `SourceList` to hold the data returned from the service layer, a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` that is bound to the `ComboBox.ItemSource`, and a property to hold the `SelectedItem`.

```
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> GetEventYearsListCommand { get; }

    private readonly SourceList<short> _eventYearsSourceList = new SourceList<short>();

    private readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<short> _eventYearsList;
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<short> EventYearsList => _eventYearsList;

    private short? _selectedEventYear;
    public short? SelectedEventYear
    {
        get => _selectedEventYear;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _selectedEventYear, value);
    }
```

In the constructor of the ViewModel I set up the subscriptions:

```
        GetEventYearsListCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(ExecuteGetEventYearsListCommand);
        GetEventYearsListCommand.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ex => Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString()));

        _eventYearsSourceList
            .Connect()
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .Bind(out _eventYearsList)
            .Subscribe();

        // when a series is selected, this fires off the command to update the event years
        this.WhenAny(x => x.SelectedSeries, _ => Unit.Default)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .InvokeCommand(GetEventYearsListCommand);
```

Note that this command is invoked when the user changes the selected item in another `ListBox`...

And finally, the command to update the `SourceList` looks like this:

```
   private async Task ExecuteGetEventYearsListCommand()
    {
        var eventYearsList = new List<short>();
        if (SelectedSeries != null)
        {
            eventYearsList = await seriesApi.QueryEventYears(SelectedSeries.OrgSeriesPath);
        }

        _eventYearsSourceList.Edit(list =>
        {
            list.Clear();
            if (eventYearsList != null) list.AddRange(eventYearsList);
        });

        // This trace shows the correct number of items in the list
        Trace.WriteLine($"_eventYearsSourceList count = {_eventYearsSourceList.Count}");

        // But here, I don't get the right count, EventYearsList has not been updated yet!!!
        Trace.WriteLine($"EventYearsList count = {EventYearsList.Count}");

        // and this check isn't even valid, because EventYearsList hasn't been updated...
        if (EventYearsList?.Count > 0)
        {
            SelectedEventYear = EventYearsList.First();
        }
    }
```

So looking at the command directly above...  I've updated the `SourceList`, but the `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` hasn't updated yet...  It still shows the contents of the `SourceList` prior to my update.

The first issue is, I'm not even getting the first item from the newly updated list, because it hasn't been updated yet.

The second issue is, even if I set the selected item right now, that selection is lost when the EventYearsList does finally update.  Because of the twoway binding on the selected item (I assume), the `SelectedEventYear` is set to null after EventYearsList does finally update.  So even if I could set the selected item right now, it would be overwritten.  (I've confirmed this behavior by setting a breakpoint on the SelectedEventYear property setter)

Either I'm doing something wrong...  Or I need to find a way to (separately) hook in to something that tells me when the underlying source for the `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` has changed.

So back to the original question...  How do I set the `SelectedItem` AFTER the update to the `ItemSource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I would do something like this as it seems to solve the problem most of the time.

```cs
    _eventYearsSourceList
        .Connect()
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .Bind(out _eventYearsList)
        .Do(_=> \\some logic to set the selected item) 
        .Subscribe();
```

Using the `Do` statement is not ideal as you will need to choose an item from `_eventYearsList`. Generally in reactive programming touching some object state outside of the function is not recommened as doing so can introduce concurrency and state issues. However, in this case you may need the first date or perhaps you will need to iterate the observable collection but the safe-guard is that the binding takes place on the main thread as will the logic inside the Do statement so you will have no concurrency issues.

Another option of course, is you can apply the logic within `Subscribe`.

Comment: We were posting the answers at the same time, as I saw you answer after I hit  post.

Comment: Ahh!  I can do both at once!  The very next thing I need to do is select not the first item, but the item that is closest to today's date (are you clairvoyant or something?).  I'll be giving that a shot right now!  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so with much hair pulling and gnashing of teeth, I figured out something that works.  No idea if this is a "good" way to do this, or if there is a "better" way (I would certainly like to hear about a better way if it exists).

The key was that I subscribe to changes of the `SourceList` twice.

Once like I was originally doing to `Bind` the `SourceList` to a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` that the view/XAML can bind to:

```
        _eventYearsSourceList
            .Connect()
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .Bind(out _eventYearsList)
            .Subscribe();
```

Then do another which simply looks for any change to the `SourceList`, and then goes and does something:

```
        _eventYearsSourceList
            .Connect()
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .Subscribe(async _ => await SelectFirstEventYear());
```

This will cause my `SelectFirstEventYear()` method to fire, where I can set the `SelectedEventYear` property to the first item.

Side Note:

For some reason, setting the `SelectedEventYear` property (which utilizes `RaiseAndSetIfChanged`) in this method did not trigger this `WhenAny` to fire:

```
        this.WhenAny(x => x.SelectedEventYear, _ => Unit.Default)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .InvokeCommand(GetEventsListCommand);
```

I'm not sure why that is...  Any time that selected item changes, I have another ListBox that needs to be updated as well, and that is what `GetEventsListCommand` does.  I ended up adding a call to that command in my `SelectFirstEventYear()` method and all seems to be playing nicely.